# IL code for attribute inheritance

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, attributes, cil

I have a basic question here. 
I have an attribute on an abstract method in a base class. Now when I implement/override this method in some derived class I do not see the attribute being applied in the IL generated for that derived class method.
But it all works fine.

Am I missing something here? How do we know that the compiler has marked the derived class method implementation to be decorated by that specific attribute?

Any hints?

Comment: Attributes are never inherited unless you instruct it

Comment: What about the TestFixtureTeardown attribute of NUnit 2.6.x?

Comment: It says in the documentation of NUnit that - "The TestFixtureTearDown attribute is inherited from any base class".

Comment: This happens at reflection time, not compile time.

Comment: Does that mean run time? Can you please point me to some useful resource or read up on this? Thanks. I know I am asking too much :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you apply an attribute that has `Inherited = true` set in its `AttributeUsage` attribute, and then call `GetCustomAttributes(inherit: true)` on a member that inherits from a member with that attribute, then you're going to get that attribute. But you're not going to see anything in the IL of the inheriting member, the compiler doesn't do anything special for it, it's reflection that looks at the base member.

For example with this code:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All, Inherited = true)]
class InheritedAttribute : Attribute
{}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All, Inherited = false)]
class NotInheritedAttribute : Attribute
{}

abstract class Base
{
    [Inherited, NotInherited]
    public abstract void M();
}

class Derived : Base
{
    public override void M()
    {}
}

…

foreach (var type in new[] { typeof(Base), typeof(Derived) })
{
    var method = type.GetMethod("M");

    foreach (var inherit in new[] { true, false })
    {
        var attributes = method.GetCustomAttributes(inherit);

        Console.WriteLine(
            "{0}.{1}, inherit={2}: {3}",
            method.ReflectedType.Name, method.Name, inherit,
            string.Join(", ", attributes.Select(a => a.GetType().Name)));
    }
}
```

You're going to get this output:

```
Base.M, inherit=True: NotInheritedAttribute, InheritedAttribute
Base.M, inherit=False: NotInheritedAttribute, InheritedAttribute
Derived.M, inherit=True: InheritedAttribute
Derived.M, inherit=False:
```

Comment: So compiler does not do anything special but at run time CLR would check whether the derived method implementation has the attribute applied or not?

Comment: I just want to know the part where compiler says that this particular method will have this particular attribute applied to it. And I am going to mark this one as the answer.

Comment: @KumarVaibhav Well, in the case of inherited attributes, the compiler doesn't say that.

Answer (score 1):

Attributes are not applied by default on derived classes unless you explicitly instruct it while creation.

The [AttributesUsage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/84c42s56%28v=vs.71%29.aspx#cpconapplyingattributeusageattribute) attribute has a property called [Inherited](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/84c42s56%28v=vs.71%29.aspx#cpconwritingcustomattributesanchor2)(of type boolean),which tells whether your attribute will be inherited by the derived classes or not.

```
[AttributeUsage( Inherited = true)]
public class CustomAttribute : Attribute
{
}

[Custom]
public class Base {
}

public class Sub : Base {
}
```

Now the `CustomAttribute` is applied/inherited by the sub class as well.